# Поиск по первому вхождению в поисковый запрос

Tags: mysql, select, полнотекстовый-поиск

Допустим, есть таблица с полем `title` и с записями

```
a
abra
abraka
```

Надо, чтобы при вводе `abrakadabra` выводил `abraka`
Движок `innobd`, поэтому `fulltext` индекс не провесить, да и не уверен, что он тут нужен.

**UPD**

Сейчас делаю таким запросом:

```
SELECT title FROM table WHERE 'abrakadabra' LIKE CONCAT(title, '%') ORDER BY title DESC LIMIT 1;
```

При таком раскладе находит простые записи, но если, например, запись будет вида `abraka foobar`, то результат пустой.

**UPD2**

Вообщем, сделал пока что влоб. Запрос у меня создаётся динамически и в результате получается что-то вроде этого:

```
SELECT title FROM table WHERE title LIKE 'abrakadabra%' or title LIKE 'abrakadabr%' or title LIKE 'abrakadab%' ...  or title LIKE 'ab%' ORDER BY title DESC LIMIT 1
```

Благо, таблица небольшая, до 1к-3к записей.

Comment: *Надо, чтобы при вводе `abrakadabra` выводил `abraka`* Сформулируйте чёткий и однозначный критерий, по которому должна быть выбрана именно эта запись.

Comment: Задача конечно кошмарная. Вы ищите множество в скаляре :) То есть при решении в лоб, вам придётся отнимать по одному символу с конца искомого и селектить его в базе, при самом консервативном прогнозе создавая length(scalar) запросов. Ужасно.

Comment: *Движок `innobd`, поэтому `fulltext` индекс не провесить* А вот документация на MySQL так не считает: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html *Full-text indexes can be used only **with InnoDB or MyISAM tables**, and can be created only for CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns.*